# Hyper-V: Running a script during VM reboot

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to promote a resource configuration change during VM reboot cycle. Preferably, I'd like to do that without user intervention, as in: I ask the VM to reboot, and between the shutdown and the start, the VM resource change is performed by a script.

However, I haven't been able to find a decent hook to execute that script.

Does such a hook exist?

I'm using win2008 Datacenter R2. I don't have access to the VM internals (we rent it out to a customer), but of course I do have full control over the host.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of such a hook, but I am not a Hyper-V expert either.

Would you be able to use a PowerShell script to accomplish the same thing?  The [PowerShell Management Library for Hyper-V](http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/) should allow you to write a script that shuts down the VM, reconfigures it however you like, and then restarts it.

Comment: This is indeed a possible route, but it requires us to reboot the system, outside of the customer's control.